# Can I use type of a variable to declare another variable in Java?

Tags: java, generics, types, dictionary

Can I do something like this in Java?

```
HashMap<String, Child> childMap=new HashMap<String, Child>();
HashMap<String, childMap.typeName> parentMap=new HashMap<String, childMap.typeName>();
//instead of
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>> parentMap=new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>>();
```

or something like this

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>> parent1=new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>>();
parent1.typeName parent2=new parent1.typeName;
```

Because some time, if the map level is too deep or too complex, it is very hard to write and read.

Comment: In short: no you can't! :) Second, the title you chose is misleading because you don't "use variable to define another" you are trying to use "type of a variable ..."

Comment: No but you could shorten it if you're using Java 7 or higher. The compiler can infer the type parameters from the left side of the assignment and you can skip them altogether while creating the object `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();` In older versions of Java, you could resord to [Guava's `Maps` class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) and its `newHashMap` method. `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>> parentMap = Maps.newHashMap();`

Comment: So...once you realize you're nesting a map within a map within a map within a map within a map, you should *really* reconsider your data structure and see if you still think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No but you could shorten it if you're using Java 7 or higher. The compiler can infer the type parameters from the left side of the assignment and you can skip them altogether while creating the object `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();`

In older versions of Java, you could resord to [Guava's Maps class and its `newHashMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMap(java.util.Map)) method. `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>> parentMap = Maps.newHashMap();`

Another thing you could possibly do is create a type that implements a certain specification of the generic `HashMap`.

```
public class HashMapStringChild extends HashMap<String, Child> {
}
```

and then use it as a type parameter

```
HashMap<String, HashMapStringChild> parent2 = new HashMap<>();
```

but personally, I find this a bit of a stretch. I certainly wouldn't overuse it and I'd be careful extending the collection classes.

### Addendum

You should also note that you're effectively binding your API to a specific implementation of the `Map` interface (`HashMap`), or even worse, in case of introducing the new class (`HashMapStringChild`), to a specific, non-standard implementation.

What if at some point, you decide to keep your `Child` objects sorted at all times? You could do this by switching to a `TreeMap` but that would mean a big deal of refactoring.

You would be better off basing your API on a more general interface. This way you could switch from

```
Map<String, Map<String, Child>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Child>>();
```

to

```
Map<String, Map<String, Child>> map = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, Child>>();
```

or

```
Map<String, Map<String, Child>> map = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Child>>();
```

or any other implementation without a hassle.

If you really want to make the map of `String` to `Child` a specific type, you could introduce an interface

```
public interface MapStringToChild extends Map<String, Child> {
}
```

Then you could keep your reference types general and use `HashMap<String, Child>`, `TreeMap<String, Child>`, `HashMapStringChild` or literally any other implementation mapping a `String` to a `Child` interchangeably, while keeping the code short.

Answer (score 4):

Abbreviations are possible by defining a subclass:

```
class Str2Child extends HashMap<String, Child>>{}
class Str2Map extends HashMap<String,Str2Child>{}

Str2Map parent1 = new Str2Map();
```